# Weird tiny spring that was stuck under one of my laptop's keyboard's key - is something broken?

Tags: laptop, keyboard, laptop-repair

I've got a Lenovo X1 Yoga.

I noticed the other day a tiny bit of plastic was lodged under one of the keys. I assumed something fell in there. Upon getting it out however it looks to be like some kind of 'spring'. Is this possibly something that has broken off underneath? Anyone know what it might be from?

This thing is tiny - like 4m accross.

[image]

Comment: Do you have a key not working properly?  Is the hinge (case hinges) working properly?

Comment: The key seems to be working correctly yes, I can't detect any fault with it.

Comment: It may be some other thing that slipped in.

Comment: One thing for sure its not a keyboard spring.